# Error: undefined method `has_attachment' for User since upgrading to Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I have just upgraded my app from Rails 6.1 to 7.0. I have been using Cloudinary with the [Attachinary](https://github.com/ThomasConnolly/attachinary) gem for users to upload their profile picture, as well as photos for news articles etc. Since upgrading, I get the error:

```
undefined method `has_attachment' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  has_many_attached
```

I change `has_attachment` to `has_one_attached` in the User model, but then no attachments are loaded. Is there any way around this?

If not, I will have no choice but to revert back to Rails 6 as all attachments will have been lost.

Comment: The latest version of the [`attachinary` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/attachinary) is more than seven years old. I am surprised that it still worked with Rails 6.1. I suggest downgrading Rails to 6.1, then migration existing attachments to [Active Storage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) and then trying to upgrade Rails again to 7.x

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know how I could migrate attachments over?

Comment: No, I am sorry, but I never worked with attachinary and have no idea how a migration path might look like.